# Selecting a six-person committee

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

In this case, let me give you an example. The statement that is also a question for us to find is " Five badminton player form a group of 9 "

Then the answer for that is   9C5 ( 9 taken 5 at a time )

please help me with this thing, the question is 
"A six person committee from your math class "

How am I going to answer that?
I honestly do not know the way I should be doing that.

Y'all has to be answering that with regards to " combination and permutation "

Comment: Your grammatical structure is off for this.  "Five badminton player form a group of 9".  I think you mean to say something more along the lines of "Five badminton players form a group *from a group of* 9."  Even then, this is a statement, not a question.  I would have phrased the question: "*There are nine people.  How many ways can a group of five be formed out of these nine people?*"

Comment: In any case, if you have $n$ distinct objects overall and you want to count how many ways you can select $k$ of them (*such that order of selection doesn't matter and repetition is not allowed*), there are $\binom{n}{k}$ ways of doing this, the binomial coefficient "n choose k", also sometimes notated $C(n,k),~C^n_k,~_nC_k$ and several more... alternatively worded, there are $\binom{n}{k}$ number of $k$-element subsets from an $n$-element set.

Comment: @JMoravitz I suspect "form" was just a typo and should have been "from". Unfortunately a typo that is quite confusing in this context.

Comment: I mean that was the statement that our teacher gave us

Comment: Do you know the meaning of $9C5$?

Comment: Our teacher told us that is has to be read by the combination of 9 taken 5 at a time

Comment: So is it some kind of logical question? Do I really have to know how many students are there in our math class? I mean we actually quite only have 48 students at our class

Comment: Should I assume?

Comment: You can just use the letter $n$ and say next to the answer that $n$ represents the number of students in the class.  You aren't necessarily required to replace $n$ by an actual number, nor are you necessarily required to finish the computation or simplification.  An answer of $\binom{n}{6}$ is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Have you studied sets and subsets? Do you know how to tell how many subsets a set $S$ has, if you know the size of the set $S$? Combinations are intimately related to numbers of subsets, so if you understand subsets well then someone might be able to explain combinations by talking about subsets.

Answer (score 1):

If your math class has $n$ people, then you will get $C^n_6$ ways of choosing because that will turn out to be choosing $6$ people from $n$ people.

As the comments below, there are 48 people in the class, so we substitute $n$ by $48$ and get $C^{48}_{6}=12271512$

Comment: Hi Mr. Culver Kean, what seems to be the the answer then?

Comment: @MarcKendrick he said the answer already... $\binom{n}{6}$, where you replace $n$ by whatever the number of people in your mathclass is.  We don't know you, your teacher, or your school, so we can't fill in $n$ for you.

Comment: So is it some kind of logical question? Do I really have to know how many students are there in our math class? I mean we actually quite only have 48 students at our class